# Can not add up variables NaN

Tags: javascript

I couldn't have the variables add up as total and neither could I make them multiply inside the var. 
What am I doing wrong?

```js
var order;
var amountsoda;
var amountbeer;
var amountwine;
var total = amountsoda + amountbeer + amountwine;

while (order != "stop") {
  order = prompt("What order would you like to add? \n\n soda 2 dollar \n beer 5 dollar \n wine 10 dollar")
  if (order == "soda") {
    amountsoda = prompt("How much " + order + " would you like to add.");
  } else if (order == "beer") {
    amountbeer = prompt("How much " + order + " would you like to add.");
  } else if (order == "wine") {
    amountwine = prompt("How much " + order + " would you like to add.");
  }
}
document.write("soda: " + amountsoda + " x 2 =" + amountsoda * 2);
document.write("<br>")
document.write("beer: " + amountbeer + " x 5 =" + amountbeer * 5);
document.write("<br>")
document.write("wine: " + amountwine + " x 10 =" + amountwine * 10);
document.write("<br>")
document.write("total: " + total);
```

Comment: parseInt is your friend

Comment: How would user comes to know I have to type `stop` to done from buying?

Comment: @NickParsons If it is a *parsable* number, it will work. `"10" * 2` returns 20. OP's NaN issue created by `undefined + undefined + undefined` for `total`. Move the total logic after `while` loop

Comment: It's for school so don't mind the weird "stop" thing prompt.

Comment: @adiga oh yes, you’re right. That was an oversight by me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to **initialize the product-amounts** and the total with '0'
2. You need to **add up the total inside the while-loop** depending on the product chosen

```js
var order;
var amountsoda = 0;
var amountbeer = 0;
var amountwine = 0;
var total = 0

while (order != "stop"){
    order = prompt("What order would you like to add? \n\n soda 2 dollar \n beer 5 dollar \n wine 10 dollar")
    if (order == "soda" ){
        amountsoda = prompt("How much " + order + " would you like to add.");
        total = total + amountsoda * 2;
    }
    else if (order == "beer"){
        amountbeer = prompt("How much " + order + " would you like to add.");
        total = total + amountbeer * 5;
    }
    else if (order == "wine"){
        amountwine = prompt("How much " + order + " would you like to add.");
        total = total + amountwine * 10;
    }

}
document.write ("soda: " + amountsoda + " x 2 =" + amountsoda*2);
document.write ("<br>")
document.write ("beer: " + amountbeer + " x 5 =" + amountbeer*5);
document.write ("<br>")
document.write ("wine: " + amountwine + " x 10 =" + amountwine*10);
document.write ("<br>")
document.write ("total: " + total);
```